# Safecracker Registration - Get the corresponding channel entry_id for a member in add-ons

Tags: safecracker-registration

I am trying to find a way to get the corresponding channel entry id of a member that was registered via Safecracker.

A variation of my question has been answered [here](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/11596/safecracker-membership-how-to-get-the-entry-id-of-a-member). However, this uses channel entry tag which means

- it can't reliably be used by other plugins, snippets, etc because of some possible parse order issues
- it is limited to template use only. Can't be used in add-ons.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: So you want some code to programmatically get entries from a specific channel by the author_id (member_id)? You don't want to use Channel Entries tag, so I assume you need some PHP code to solve this problem?

Comment: @JustinKimbrell To a certain extent, yes. My 2 reasons are 1) that it eliminates complicated code in the templates 2) I want to make parse order issues irrelevant.